CloudFrontがLINEサーバーからのアクセスに署名しない
AWS初心者です。
LambdaでLINEbotを作ろうとしていて、LINEサーバーとLambdaの間にはCloudFrontを挟んでいます。
しかし
curlやブラウザからのアクセス：関数URLからLambdaに到達できる
LINEサーバーからのアクセス　：関数URLのIAM認証で弾かれる
という現象が発生しています。
関数URLの認証を無効にしたらLINEサーバーからもアクセスできるようになったので、CloudFrontがLINEサーバーからのアクセスにだけ署名を行っていないのではないのかと考えています。
解決策をご教示いただけますと幸いです。
【CloudFrontの設定】
・オリジンリクエストポリシー：AllViewerExceptHostHeader
・オリジンアクセス　　　　　：常にリクエストに署名する
・オリジンタイプ　　　　　　：Lambda function URL
